# How to view project's members on GitHub?

Tags: github

Being a project's members means they have right to commit patches. I want to get a list of these developers of projects on GitHub. How to view project's members on GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the GitHub API and [list project collaborators](https://developer.github.com/v3/projects/collaborators/#list-collaborators)

```
GET /projects/:project_id/collaborators
```

That would give you the list programmatically.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, only an organization owner or a project admin can use this command to list collaborators. For other persons, is it possible to view a project's members? @VonC

Comment: @Sunflowers Not that I know of. In your case, I assumed you were a project admin.